# Fire when task finished with promise

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, asynchronous, promise

I have this JavaScript Code:

```
members.reduce((chain, el) => {
          return chain
          .then(() => db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("user_data").doc("u").get())
          .then(doc => {
            const data = doc.data();
  // do some stuff
            return table_number;
          })
          .then(table_num => {
            return db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").doc("g").collection(education_part).get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
              querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                const data = doc.data();
                //DO SOME STUFF AGAIN AFTER FIRST TASK FINISHED 
              });
            })
          })
        }, Promise.resolve());
```

How I can fire when all these tasks are finished? Thanks in advance
~filip

**EDIT**
Here is the //DO SOME STUFF AGAIN AFTER FIRST TASK FINISHED. This is synchronous, but this solution `}, Promise.resolve()).then(console.log("finished"));` doesnt even work.

```
    var filteredMDl = 0, filteredKLU = 0, local_averagePoints = 0;

    addToTable("grade_table" + table_num, doc.id, filteredMDl, filteredKLU, local_averagePoints);
    //Adds data to an HTML table
```

Comment: `members.reduce((chain, el) => { ....... }, Promise.resolve()).then( fire away!!! )`

Comment: Is there anything asynchronous going on in `DO SOME STUFF AGAIN...`? If so, you need to return a promise in that particular `then` callback.

Comment: @trincot How to do that?

Comment: Using `Promise.all`, but your question's code does not show what async stuff you do there, so it is hard to provide an answer.

Comment: @trincot Can you please have a look at my Edit? :)

Comment: There are many dependencies in your code. Could you reduce your code sample to the bare minimum, but still producing your problem?

Comment: @trincot Like this? :)

Comment: And what exactly do you mean when you say "doesnt even work"? What happens?

Comment: @trincot It fires to early when the task even isn't finished.

Comment: Which task are you referring to? What you describe can only happen if you don't await an asynchronous execution somewhere. Is `doc.data()` async? Is `querySnapshot.forEach` async? Etc.. etc..

Comment: @trincot I am using firebase. Firebase is completely asynchronously. But I think the forEach and doc.data() is synchronous.

Comment: I would: (1) add the `firebase` tag to your question; (2) add `console.log` in your question's code, and indicate how they output in the wrong order. That way it is clear where exactly you notice that a "task" is not yet completed.